# How to get return value from callback function in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

The `get_customers()` function queries the database for the `playlists` records and logs to the console each row. But the `data` array is returned as an empty list array. How to return the data from the get_playlists function?

```
...result undefined
```

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the database.');
});



function get_playlists(db){
    let sql = `SELECT DISTINCT Name name FROM playlists
               ORDER BY name`;

    let data = []
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        console.log(row.name);
        data.push(row.name);
      });
      return data
    });
}

result = get_playlists(db)
console.log('...result', result);
db.close();
```

Comment: console.log is running before db.all is finished. Wrapp the contents of get_playlists in a promise and resolve it with `data`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content of `get_playlists` function in `Promise` and resolve with `rows`:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the database.');
});


function get_playlists(db) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        let sql = `SELECT DISTINCT Name name FROM playlists ORDER BY name`;

        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            resolve(rows);
        });
    })
}


let rows ; 
get_playlists(db).then( res => {
    rows = res;
    rows.forEach( (row) => { console.log('row:', row) } );

});

db.close();
```